# Rectangle on master footer in InDesign doesn't appear in pdf

Tags: adobe-indesign, master-page

I add a rectangle and some text at the footer of a master page. They are all there in InDesign, but when I export it to pdf, the rectangle disappears. I check layer of the rectangle, it's visible. What else do I need to change to ensure that the rectangle appears in pdf and also print-out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try to select the object and open the *Attributes* panel (*Window > Output > Attributes*).

Make sure that the object isn't set to "Nonprinting".

[image]

Comment: Thanks Wolff for that. It's in fact not selected, but not appear in pdf. I tried to select it, then deselect it, and it worked. So I guess it's error of InDesign. At least I learn if that happens again, we select nonprinting, export to pdf, then come back to InDesign and deselect it.